# Instanceof - using classes to simulate system access

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to simulate a system access portal using classes and methods. I want to be able to ask the user for their username using input(), check if that input is an object of class User and if so, check if the password is correct for the username. When I use instance of it is returning false. How can I modify this to work?

```
class User(): 

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def change_pw(self, new_password):
        self.password = new_password



jshannon = User("jshannon","AbC!23")
print(jshannon.username)
print(jshannon.password)

jshannon.change_pw("(i*u&y1")
print(jshannon.password)


input_user = input("What is your username? ")


print(isinstance(input_user, User))
```

Comment: What version of Python? 3.x?

Comment: Why would `isinstance(input_user, User)` ever be `True`? `input` returns a string (at least in Python 3.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.x (which I'm going to assume), `input` returns a string so `isinstance(input_user, User)` will always be `False`.

You will need to keep track of all `User` objects created and search for the object with the inputted name.

There are several different ways to do that. I'm going to assume that usernames are unique so I will use them in a shared set:

```
class User:
    users = set()

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.users.add(username)

    def change_pw(self, new_password):
        self.password = new_password


jshannon = User("jshannon", "AbC!23")
print(jshannon.username)
print(jshannon.password)

jshannon.change_pw("(i*u&y1")
print(jshannon.password)

input_user = input("What is your username? ")

print(input_user in User.users)
# will output True if input_user is jshannon, otherwise False
```

Note that this is just an example, and it is not bullet-proof nor the best design (one may argue if the `users` set even belongs to the `User` class *Hint: probably not*). If an object's username changes after the initialization the set will not be updated and you may get wrong results. This particular problem can be solved by changing `self.username` to a property but I suppose that is out of scope of this Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

User inputs are strings. Always. Period. So you can not "check if that input is an object of class User" - it will never be.

The solution here is to maintain a collection of `User` instances, and use the input string to search for a matching user.

```
class UsersCollection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # we store users in a dict, with user.usernale as key
        self._users = {}

    def add(self, user):
        if user.username in self._users:
            raise ValueError("username '{}' already in used".format(user.username))
        self._users[user.username] = user

    def get(self, username):
        return self._users.get(username)


users = UsersCollection()
users.add(User("jshannon","AbC!23"))

input_user = input("What is your username? ").strip()

userfound = users.get(input_user)
if userfound:
   # you can do something with your user
else:
   print("sorry, we don't know you")
```

Note that this is only suitable as a toy project of course.

Comment: Unlike the other two answers, this one allows to easily do the mentioned password match as well. Out of curiousity: why that `try - except` construct in `UsersCollection.get` instead of `return self._users.get(username)`? Other than being more explicit, what is the advantage? Do I miss something?

Comment: @shmee actually I originally planned on raising a custom exception, and finally decided otherwise but didn't fixed the code accordingly <g> (done BTW, thanks for spotting this).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want to do but you cant try this 
add a list to your class `list_of_usernames = []` 
and then in `__init__()` append username to the `list_of_usernames` and at the end

```
print(input_user in User.list_of_usernames)
```

so your code will look like this

```
class User():
list_of_usernames = []
def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.list_of_usernames.append(username)
def change_pw(self, new_password):
    self.password = new_password



jshannon = User("jshannon","AbC!23")
print(jshannon.username)
print(jshannon.password)

jshannon.change_pw("(i*u&y1")
print(jshannon.password)


input_user = input("What is your username? ")


print(input_user in User.list_of_usernames)
```